# Why is the android build system not including R.class in a library project, and how do I fix this?

Tags: android, r.java-file

In Eclipse I've converted an Android application project to a library project. The library is used by other application projects.

The `R.java` file is generated in the library, but when I check in the `.jar` file it is not there.

In the library the `R` file is in a package: `com.library.R.java`.
In the app I have `com.app.R.java`.
The library needs to use `R` from the library, and imports `com.library.R`, but it is not found.
The `com.app.R` file includes all the definitions from the library and the app.

Why is the Android build system not including `R.class` in the library project, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you need to clean the project before building the jar and be sure that the R.java is still there.  The most common reason that the R file is missing is because one of the xml files has a mistake.  I'm hoping it is something this simple.

Comment: I have tried all that. Just to be sure though I deleted the library R.java file and regenerated it. This worked as it should. I did notice that R.class is correctly in the classes directory in the library project. So I need to figure out why com.library.R.class doesn't end up in the final application.

Comment: OK. If the class file is there in the jar, you need to find out why the import in the final app isn't seeing it... stating the obvious sometimes helps. There is a quirk in Eclipse that the libs need to be above the final project paths in the Project Properties | Java Build Path Order and Export. I'm not sure the significance of the check marks in that window, but I have all of the jar files checked.

Comment: Actually, deleting R.java solved the problem. I thought I had done that before, but this time the library R.java file also appeared in the gen folder in the app project. That's the first time I've seen that, and it seems to be what is required. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `getResources().getIdentifier()`

i.e. `getResources().getIdentifier("home", "id", "android.support.v7.appcompat")`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but this is expected behaviour, check

http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

> Important change:  We have changed the way Library Projects generate
>   and package R classes: The R class is not packaged in the jar output
>   of Library Projects anymore. Library Project do not generate the R
>   class for Library Projects they depend on. Only main application
>   projects generates the Library R classes alongside their own.

Anyone know why is this change?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how I fixed this, but I tried a lot of things including completely rebuilding etc. What solved it in the end though was deleting the library R.java and then rebuilding. Somehow this triggered the addition of com.library.R.java into the gen folder of the app project, which seems to be what should have happened in the first place.

Comment: In Android you need to 'jiggle' things a little, and sometimes they fall into place :)  Keep a sense of humor.